# Objective-C Time-based Observer Pattern

Tags: ios, objective-c

In Objective-C, what is the best way to wait to execute something at a certain time (set as a timestamp that could be passed to the observer object to know what time to wait for).

For example, I would like set a time for something to 'finish' in the future, like building a house, and when the current time is the time that was set as a completion time by the app the app will send a notification or send a message to another object.

What is best way to do this in Objective-C?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It seems like the best way to do this is to launch a thread with a delay.  If you need that to be at a certain time, just take the difference from [NSDate date] (now) and the time you want it to launch.

Comment: There's definitely no need to create another thread. ObjC tends not to create threads just to wait for something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about something that happens during the run of the program (rather than "busing a house" being a real house that gets built months from now).

The normal tool for this is `-[NSTimer initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`]. This will let you set a specific time to call a method. It just schedules the event on the runloop, which is very cheap. `NSTimer` is ideal for things that are not time-critical and have fairly long delays (more than a few seconds).